BoxAnnotator is deprecated
I'm uploading a project from Roboflow to my program. returns an error:

Supervision Warnings: BoxAnnotator is deprecated: BoxAnnotator is deprecated and will be removed in supervision-0.22.0. Use Bounding Box Annotation and Label Annotator instead
visit https://app.roboflow.com/auth-cli to get your authentication token.

program code:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import roboflow  
from inference import get_model

roboflow.login()
#export ROBOFLOW_API_KEY="my_key"
rf = Roboflow(api_key="my_key")
project = rf.workspace("bottle-ixxqe").project("bottle-al9vg")
version = project.version(1)
dataset = version.download("yolov8")
model = get_model(model_id="yolov8n-640")
results = model.infer("https://media.roboflow.com/inference/people-walking.jpg")


what's wrong?
recommendations about the BoxAnnotator I didn't find it.

You have one warning and one prompt, but neither should be causing an error. Your script is likely just waiting for you to enter your auth token. Here's a explanation for both:
Deprecation warning:
The BoxAnnotator deprecation warning should not appear if you don't use it somewhere in your code. From your imports, it looks like you might have some other code you didn't share. The BoxAnnotator which used to annotate labels and boxes based on detections is being deprecated, so you need to use BoundingBoxAnnotator and LabelAnnotator.
So previously, if you had:
box_annotator = sv.BoxAnnotator()

annotated_frame = box_annotator.annotate(
    scene=image.copy(),
    detections=detections,
    labels=labels
)

You now need to have:
bounding_box_annotator = sv.BoundingBoxAnnotator()
label_annotator = sv.LabelAnnotator()

annotated_frame = image.copy()

annotated_frame = bounding_box_annotator.annotate(
    scene=annotated_frame,
    detections=detections
)
annotated_frame = label_annotator.annotate(
    scene=annotated_frame,
    detections=detections,
    labels=labels
)

It's also possible that you used a package that uses Supervision, in which case the authors of that package need to update it, but with all that said its a warning, not an error. Until you install v0.22 (which isn't out yet), it should work fine.
Authentication prompt
The message Visit https://app.roboflow.com/auth-cli to get your authentication token. is not an error, but a prompt for you to enter a token instead of a API key, triggered by the roboflow.login() method.
Since it looks like you are already are authenticating with an an API key, you can remove the line roboflow.login().
